# Applying a function to a list of dates

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, twitter, apply

Good morning guys!

I have a question to do with the looping of a function. I have spent a few hours trying to figure it out, I suspect the answers are out there I just don't quite know the right question to ask so I'll try and articulate it here. I'm using the twitteR() package to pull down tweets and trying to write a function that you can specify a range of dates and it will pull down the tweets for each day in that range eg days 1:10 and it pulls down tweets from {1:2 2:3 ... 9:10}

In the `searchtwitter()` function there is a place for since="" and until="" these take data in the format of "yyyy-mm-dd". So that's the ground work my approach has been to try and generate to sequences of dates using say `x<-seq(as.Date(x), length.out="", by="1 day")` and then another  starting the next day. This gives us two sequences lets say x and y. I then want to apply the searchtwitter() function to those to generate a list of tweets for each x and y value. I was originally just trying to do this with the sapply() function as follows

```
sapply(x, searchTwitter("qantas", n=1, cainfo="cacert.pem", retryOnRateLimit=99999, since=x))
```

This isn't however, working as i think the date is treated as a chr causing error perhaps??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to see where your function bugging without including the code here.  I'd imagine you have to create a loop for each day in the sequence and wrap the sequence in a paste function.  ie: x <- paste(seq(from = as.Date(x), to = as.Date(y)))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` and `y` contain dates that you want to query between, something like (note, `...` just means the rest of your arguments for you to type in, I just go lazy):

```
mapply(function(a, b) searchTwitter(since=a, until=b, "qantas", ...), x, y)
```

should work.  Whenever you use the `apply` style functions, the FUN argument needs to be a function, NOT a **call** to a function.  In your case, you were using a **call** to a function.  In this case, we created a function that accepts two arguments, and wrapped that around `searchTwitter` so that we can explicitly specify the `since` and `until` arguments.

If `searchTwitter` required only one date argument, here is what you could do:

```
sapply(x, function(a) searchTwitter(since=a, ...))
```

Note how for `sapply` the function is the second argument.  Finally, if `since` were the first formal argument of `seachTwitter`, then you wouldn't need the wrapper and could do this directly:

```
sapply(x, searchTwitter, n=1, cainfo=...)
```

Notice how we pass a function as the second argument, not a function call.  This only works if the value you are applying over is intended to go into the first argument of the function.  Otherwise you need the wrapper as shown in the prior examples.  The wrappers in these examples are not function calls, but rather, actual function objects.

Some examples of what I mean by call vs. function:

- `mean(1:3)`                             # this is a call
- `mean`                                  # this is a function
- `function(x) sum(x)/count(x)`           # this is a function too
- `(function(x) sum(x)/count(x))(1:3)`    # this is a call

Basically, a call returns the result of the function, whereas the function returns the function itself.  Type the above in your command line to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(twitteR)
dates <- as.Date(0:9,origin="2014-01-01")  # first 10 days of 2014
get.tweets <- function(date) {
  searchTwitter("qantas", n=1, cainfo="cacert.pem", retryOnRateLimit=99999, 
                since=as.character(date), until=as.character(date+1))
}
tweets <- sapply(dates,get.tweets)
```

This (should...) grab tweets one day at a time for the first 10 days of 2014. When I run it the call to `searchTwitter(...)` fails because I'm not authenticated.

Note that `since=...` and `until=...` are char, not date. I created the function `get.tweets(date)` separately for clarity, but you could use an "anonymous" function that is defined in the call to `sapply(...)`:

```
tweets <- sapply(dates,function(date)     
              searchTwitter("qantas", n=1, cainfo="cacert.pem", 
                            retryOnRateLimit=99999, 
                            since=as.character(date), 
                            until=as.character(date+1)))
```

Finally, if you have two sets of dates there is a way using `sapply(...)`:

```
since <- as.Date(0:9,origin="2014-01-01")  # first 10 days of Jan 2014
until <- as.Date(0:9,origin="2014-02-01")  # first 10 days of Feb 2014
dates <- data.frame(since,until)
get.tweets <- function(i) {
  searchTwitter("qantas", n=1, cainfo="cacert.pem", retryOnRateLimit=99999, 
                since=as.character(dates[i,]$since), 
                until=as.character(dates[i,]$until))
}
tweets <- sapply(1:10,get.tweets)
```

This just binds the `since` and `until` values into a data frame (called `dates`), and then passes the row index of `dates` to the function in `sapply(...)`.